# Paid Membership Pro - Profile Description is invalid

Tags: wordpress, paypal, payment-gateway

I'm using Paid Membership Pro in WordPress. I'm using Express PayPal. After checkout it returns to my website and there's an error:

> Profile **Description is Invalid**

I'm not sure what's this error and how to fix it.

Comment: Please refrain from urgent begging here - read this [community discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495).

Comment: Paid Membership Pro is a paid plugin; ask for help from their support.

Answer (score 1):

I work at Paid Memberships Pro at stumbled upon this thread accidentally. I know this is an older thread but thought to post this here for future reference.

If you experience a "Profile Description is Invalid" error (or something similar) when using PayPal Express, the most likely cause of this is a missing Site Title and/or Site description.

For more information, you can view this blog post: https://www.paidmembershipspro.com/security-header-is-not-valid/